# How attacker can access victim's account without knowing its credentials?

Tags: cookies, session-management

I want to login facebook from a wifi connection and check sign-in page is over https but later when i don't pay attention to address bar (for example when playing games and click on links like a crazy person quickly) can attacker by man-in-the-middle-attack send me a facebook page in http and see my cookie then use that cookie to use my account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not speaking for Facebook specifically, but in any decently configured Web server, the cookies sent over HTTPS are marked "secure" and the browser will not send them back to the server if not using HTTPS (from the browser point of view, if the name is the same but not the protocol, then it is not the same server).

Of course, a user who crazily clicks without paying attention... that's the root of all vulnerabilities.

Comment: but Thomas honestly when you for example surfing on facebook or any site, check address bar for every page ? we are professional and don't check, regular people for sure will not ...  the question is if attacker MITM victim and victim have no HTTPSanywhere then why not attacker success ?

Comment: for example you click on https:facebook.com/credit but i inject you http:blahblah.ws/com which have an inframe of http:facebook.com/profile/goodpicturesofanunimportantperson or just http facebook pages directly to you. then your browser send all data to that server over http

Comment: @pier: in that situation, my browser sees `blahblah.ws` and will NOT send the cookies which have been recorded for `https://facebook.com/`, regardless of how much, as a human user, I am convinced to interact with the true Facebook site or not.

Comment: well if browser see http:facebook.com/profile/xxx then send data to facebook over http

Comment: And yet the browser will NOT send to `http://facebook.com/` a cookie which has been initially set by `https://facebook.com/`. The human user may not see the extra 's', but the browser minds it and takes care.

Comment: so attacker must send the initial login page over http to user to see cookie over http ?

Comment: Yes, if the attacker wants to hijack the cookie (or get the password), he must make a fake login page and convince the user to type his password in it. There is nothing that Facebook can do against that. But if the user takes care to type his password only in a properly HTTPS-authenticated Facebook page, then he should be safe from _that_.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible because Facebook uses HTTPS for everything.   You can MITM Security.StackExchange.com and StackoverFlow.com and [no one cares](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69171/why-doesnt-the-stack-overflow-team-fix-the-firesheep-style-cookie-theft).

Other than an [OWASP a9 violation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection),  there are plenty of other vulnerablites that allow you to access a victom's account.  XSS, CSRF,  Insecure Direct Object Reference,  SQL Injection...  The list goes on.